# Connection between the Big Bang and Black Holes

Tags: black-holes, big-bang

So... this is my first question here after a little while of lurking; so be gentle.

I've been thinking lately about trying to wrap my head around the concept of spacetime and how it can be affected by gravity and the density of matter in space (i.e. near a black hole).

I've been wondering. Is it possible that matter - which is broken down (spaghettified?) into it's constituent parts and into energy - is drawn to a point in spacetime which has already got a massive density?

Would it be possible that any black hole, which has been or will ever be, causes energy to be drawn to a single point in space or time? I.E. all black holes are "feeding" into a single, infinitesimal time and location; causing (possibly the wrong word - it seems to me that it would be less cause vs. effect and more that it just *is*) the big bang?

I tried to find some papers that would touch on the topic but couldn't find anything specific - which likely means I'm being a total dolt and there are many good reasons why this isn't the case :)

I would appreciate any information which would correct my thinking and counter my naivety.

Comment: It's not surprising you found no papers about this. The Big Bang is a moment in time, whereas black holes are objects that first formed long after. Asking if a set of objects are intimately linked (contribute, even) to the existence of a moment of time that passed in the far chronological past of all the objects in the set just makes no sense. It's not that I'm trying to dismiss the idea; it literally is non-sensical. It's like asking if the smell of all the collective cheeses in France is causing the year 10 000 BCE to do the waltz.

Comment: I may have exaggerated slightly and been too frank, but as a cosmologist, I hear two or three extremely non-sensical questions a day. So nothing personal. It's actually great that you checked papers first; shows potential.

Comment: Jim, don't worry. You'll have to do much better than that to cause me offense :p I think I understand your frustration here with my understanding of the Big Bang. You say it's considered a point in time rather than an object. I can understand that but surely it's an event and therefore a physical "thing"? I think that might be at the root of my question: has their ever been any hypothesis that large gravitational fields can influence energy in space time in the way it does with matter in typical/traditional space?

Comment: It isn't an event. It is purely a moment of time. It is usually defined as the moment when the scale factor of the metric is equal to 0. There is no "explosion" of energy. Simply stated, after the Big Bang, the scale factor (which dictates the measurable size of distances) increases. That is space expansion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection between different black holes, so there is no sense in which matter that falls into two separate black holes can end up being part of the same Big Bang.

Technically we can calculate a property called the [proper distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_length) between two test particles falling into the two separate black holes. In the Big Bang the proper distance between every pair of points in the universe was zero, so the proper distance between our two test particles would have to fall to zero for them to end up at the same Big Bang, and it does not do so.

having said that, there are [physicists who believe that](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/2014/06/10/the-logic-and-beauty-of-cosmological-natural-selection/) in every black hole the singularity at the centre produces a Big Bang in a new disconnected universe. If this is true (to be fair most of us think it isn't) then our two particles could end up as part of two separate Big Bangs in to new separate universes.

Comment: Yes, physicists like Roger Penrose. So Askanison4, don't be too discouraged by the answers. You're thinking like a pro.

Comment: @tau1777: as far as I know Roger Penrose has never suggested that a black hole produces a big bang in a new universe - I was thinking of Lee Smolin. In any case, no criticism is implied.

Comment: The notion that a black hole in our universe might cause a black hole in another universe resonates with me on some level but I can't find the logic of multiple universes making much sense to me. That's what drew me to thinking of time in our universe to be more like space and that a force might draw energy toward it like a sinkhole - much in the same way space behaves. I know it's all conjecture, obviously - but everything I've read about the way large gravitation fields warp space AND time around dense objects leads me to believe it is possible they behave in similar ways.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I was just thinking about a talk he gave at my University. It is very possible I'm misremembering. No critism taken.